# Using a tableadapter how do I query my db table in the code behind page

Tags: sql, vb.net, visual-studio-2013

I have TableAdapter name ballotsTableAdapter and I want to use it to query my db table ballots without adding it as a query to the table, if that makes sense.

```
Dim adapter As New eVoteTableAdapters.ballotsTableAdapter
Dim ballot_IDIn As Integer = ballot_ID
Dim name As String
Dim sd As Date
Dim ed As Date
name = CType(adapter.Adapter.SelectCommand.ExecuteScalar(SELECT name FROM ballots WHERE ballod_ID = @ballot_IDIn), String)
sd = CType(adapter.Adapter.SelectCommand.ExecuteScalar(SELECT startDate FROM ballots WHERE ballod_ID = @ballot_IDIn), Date)
ed = CType(adapter.Adapter.SelectCommand.ExecuteScalar(SELECT endDate FROM ballots WHERE ballod_ID = @ballot_IDIn), Date)
```

Sorry in advance I am sure this is a amateur question.

Comment: Surround your queries with `"` to make it a string - `SELECT name FROM ballots WHERE ballod_ID = @ballot_IDIn` becomes `$"SELECT name FROM ballots WHERE ballod_ID = {ballot_IDIn}"` - for starters.

Comment: I just did that and got error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: @AlexM., please do not advise using string concatenation for creating sql queries even for starters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need provide query as a string and provide sql parameters for your query

```vb
Public Function GetName(ballotId As Interger) As String
    Dim query As String = "SELECT name FROM ballots WHERE ballod_ID = @ballot_IDIn"
    Using connection = New SqlConnection("connection string")
        Using command = New SqlCommand(query, connection)
            Dim parameter = New SqlParameter With
            {
                .ParameterName = "ballot_IDIn",
                .SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int,
                .Value = ballotId 
            }
            command.Parameters.Add(parameter)
            connection.Open()
            Dim result = commnad.ExecuteScalar()
            Return result.ToString()
        End Using
    End Using
End Function
```

I suggest using separate SqlCommand without TableAdapter and even create new instance of `SqlConnection` for every query.